# Changing canvas size dynamically

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib

I want to plot multiple time-series (each time-series in its own plot) using the `plot()`-method of matplotlib.

- X-Axis: Time
- Y-Axis: Parameter-Value

As the time-series have different lengths, I want to resize the canvas along the X-Axis dynamically, so that the time-series do not get stretched/compressed dependent on their total length. The size of the whole figure should stay the same, independent of the time-series-length. I know how to modify the figure size using

```
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = width, height
```

but I do only want to modify the canvas size (the part of the figure where the time-series is actually plotted in). Is there a similar way of just changing the figure's canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to change the dimensions of the axes that your time-series is being plotted in, rather than the dimensions of the figure canvas (which as far as I'm aware can't be altered without changing the overall figure size).

You can do this using `ax.set_position()`, which takes a tuple of (left, bottom, width, height) values in normalized canvas coordinates between 0 and 1.

Comment: this works just fine. I defined the plot-"length" in `canvasLength` and then used `ax.set_position(pos = [0,0,canvasLength,1])`

Comment: please note that you also have lots of other options. you could just set the x-limits for each of your plots to match the duration of the longest timeseries, so the size of each set of axes will be the same and the aspect ratio of the data will also be equal. or you could use `ax.set_aspect(num)` to enforce a constant aspect ratio for each set of axes.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pylab import *
nr = 4
nc = 1
fig,axes = subplots(nr,nc,sharex=True)
```

The `sharex` keyword tells the subplots to keep their x limits the same.  Replace `plot` in your application with `axes[ith index].plot`, etc.